# WinSCP Installation Issue

Tags: wine

I have installed Wine and after that i tried install the WinSCP and i get this error

`C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\DragExt64.dll
unable to register the DLL/OCX:RegSvr32 failed with exit code 0x1.
Click retry to try again, ignore to proceed anyway (not recommended), or Abort to cancel installation`

Comment: I suspect this specific case might be a 32/64 bit mismatch between WINE and the program you're trying to install, but as the comments note, installing WinSCP on Linux doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I've been using WinSCP on Linux for all my web dev workflows for over 6 years now. Here is my GitHub Repo with instructions: https://github.com/JavaScriptDude/WinSCP_On_Wine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why on earth would you want WinSCP on Linux? WinSCP is itself a compatibility layer for Windows.

Native file managers like Nautilus and Dolphin have native support for SFTP.

Comment: I am new to Linux OS so i saw somewhere that i can run winSCP through wine so i was trying that thing anyways Dolphin helped :)

Comment: But Nautilus and Dolphin do not have support of SCP. I also need this badly, but there is nothing available but poor support of MC and CLI. This is not an answer.

Comment: WinSCP has some very powerful sync features that is not available in GUI form in other applications. These sync features are very handy for doing web development as change sets can be easily synchronized out to various dev/test/prod servers. WinSCP is a standard part of my development workflows and I've been using Linux as my primary desktop for 6 years now.

Answer (score 2):

Install on WINE 32 bit prefix and work!

export WINEPREFIX='anyfolder'
export WINEARCH='win32'
wine 'wineboot' 
wine 'winscpinstaller'

Answer (score 1):

1. Find out and Download WinSCP virtual application from here: http://online.cameyo.com/public
2. Install wine on your linux
3. Run this virtual application with wine. (I can use it on UBUNTU 14.04 without any problems)

Answer (score 1):

For those who actually depend on WinSCP for workflows like automated file synchronization on remote hosts that use FTP like windows servers, I have made a repository in GitHub that explains how to install WinSCP on Linux including making a App Icon for Ubuntu Gnome or other XDG supporting X system.

[Here is the Repo](https://github.com/JavaScriptDude/WinSCP_On_Wine)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use [scp](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/TransferFiles) from the terminal yet?

Or is there a specific reason you need to run WinSCP?

Comment: Beyond supporting multiple protocols beyond SCP, WinSCP has some very powerful sync features that is not available in GUI form in other applications. These sync like features are very handy for doing web development as change sets can be easily synchronized out to various dev/test/prod servers. WinSCP is a standard part of my development workflows and I've been using Linux as my primary desktop for 6 years now. Yes, rsync can do great syncronization on an ad-hoc basis but for day to day workflows, a GUI is much better to go with.